# SSRS 2008 - Refreshing Cached Shared Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportmanager

I have a few shared datasets on which I have enabled caching on in Report Manager (SSRS 2008 R2).  They are used to populate parameter values, and need to be refreshed on the first of each month.  I am attempting to create a Cache Refresh Plan through the Shared Dataset > Manage > Cache Refresh Options.  After creating the refresh plan, clicking OK, and clicking OK once again under 'Refresh the cache according to the following schedule:,' I am prompted with the following error message:

**An attempt has been made to use an event type 'RefreshCache' that is not registered with this report server for external use. (rsUnknownEventType)'"**

Is anyone familiar with this error and of a way to bypass it?  Although I could simply allow the cache to expire on the 1st of each month, I do not want to burden the end-user with wait times during which a new cache is being built on the first run on the first of each month.

I should also mention that I am not assigned the System Administrator role on the Report Manager.  I'm just a lowly Content Manager.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02c93dc3-b8dd-4d9c-8cb6-66384b50c472/error-when-trying-to-create-cache-refresh-plan-for-a-shared-dataset?forum=sqlreportingservices)?

Comment: David, thank you. I came across that link, but lack access to the rsReportServer.config file.  I may end up having to reach out to the admins to implement a fix.